# Android Studio 0.2.5 Does not see Galaxy S4 as device

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

I've googled all over the place and have yet to find an answer.  I have a new Galaxy S4 and just downloaded Android Studio.  I'm trying to run my first Hello World app on my phone, yet Android Studio 0.2.5 does not see the device.  I have enabled Dev mode on my S4 as I've read, but still no go.  I even tried restarting my S4.

Anyone have any sort of idea what might be the issue?

Comment: When you plugged in your phone, did you accept the security dialog prompt on you phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a Galaxy S3 and initially I did not know what to do when I was in the same position as you are.

The Android page on making your device recognizable via USB is slightly misleading. So what is the way out ?

Well, download and install `Samsung Kies` and let it do its work. It will install all the necessary drivers to make your device recognizable.

Happy coding.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a ton, Little Child!  Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Windows, you can try to go to Device Manager, right-click your phone, click Update Driver Software, then you should select Browse my computer for driver software, click Next and click Browse and locate the USB driver folder and point to your `<android_sdk>\extras\google\usb_driver\` folder.

You can find more detailed instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html).

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "USB debugging" under Settings > Developer Options is checked. Then a security pop-up should appear to allow the computer to connect.